# Reading ReST response in an Angular Controller with Restangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular controller I have:

```
var r= Restangular.one('clients/auth').get();
console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
```

However, the js console only shows "{}"
When I use a browser ReST client, I see what I expect, which is an email address string.
How do I use "r" (and see it)?
I want to compare "r", and do operations on it, for instance, see if it is a certain email.

I'm using Go as the backend on Google App Engine, and I have (I'm using gorilla):

```
func GetClientAuth(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

  c := appengine.NewContext(r)
  u := user.Current(c)
  gorca.WriteJSON(c, w, r, u.Email)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restangular `get()` returns a promise. So try this:

```
Restangular.one('clients/auth').get().then(function(result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```